# Adjusting fill in ggvis that has mapped a variable to it

Tags: r, ggvis

When using `ggplot` I can adjust the colors manually when a variable is mapped to it. Like the following example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'green', 'blue'))
```

I would like to do the same in `ggvis`. The only solution I found so far is hard coding the color name in the data and assigning this by `fill := ~variable_name`. I hope someone can tell me what to add to the following

```
ggvis(mtcars, ~cyl, ~mpg, fill = ~factor(cyl)) %>%
   layer_points()
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change fill colors for a categorical variable with `scale_nominal`.  You use `"fill"` as the name of the property you want to control and give the colors you want via `range`.

```
ggvis(mtcars, ~cyl, ~mpg, fill = ~factor(cyl)) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    scale_nominal("fill", range =  c('red', 'green', 'blue'))
```